# Create list of list where the split point are integers

Tags: python

Let's consider that I have a list like the following one:

```
myList = [
    '1000', 'ParameterName=Device type', 'ObjectType=0x7', 'DataType=0x7',
    'AccessType=ro', 'PDOMapping=0', 'ObjFlags=1', 'ParameterValue=0x00020192',
    '1001', 'ParameterName=Error register', 'ObjectType=0x7', 'DataType=0x5',
    'AccessType=ro', 'PDOMapping=0', 'ObjFlags=1', 'ParameterValue=0x00',
    '1003', 'SubNumber=6', 'ParameterName=Error history', 'ObjectType=0x8'
]
```

My split points will be `'1000'`, `'1001'` and `'1003'` where the objective is to have

```
listoflists = [
    ['1000', 'ParameterName=Device type', 'ObjectType=0x7', 'DataType=0x7',
     'AccessType=ro', 'PDOMapping=0', 'ObjFlags=1', 'ParameterValue=0x00020192'],
    ['1001', 'ParameterName=Error register', 'ObjectType=0x7', 'DataType=0x5',
     'AccessType=ro', 'PDOMapping=0', 'ObjFlags=1', 'ParameterValue=0x00'],
    ['1003', 'SubNumber=6', 'ParameterName=Error history', 'ObjectType=0x8']
]
```

I can easily do it with a simple for loop as follows.

There are some extra checks as I asked for the nominal case but the number can be an hex (so I use `is_numeric`) and also it can be with a different format such as 4digit+string (`1234sub2`) so I slice the data. The last check is because as I use the `is_digit` some hex can be considered data when it is really text but as always that his happens there is an `'DataThatMaybeIsConfusedAsHex = value'` I can discriminate using the `'='`.

```
for value in configurationFileList:
    if is_numeric(value[:4]) and counter != 0 and "=" not in value:

        # Append the list to the list of lists
        configurationFileListForEachIndex.append(tmpList.copy())

        # Clear the list
        tmpList.clear()

        # Append the New Index
        tmpList.append(value)

    else:
        tmpList.append(value)

    counter += 1
```

I would like to ask if there is any 'prettier' and more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank you, just knowing the formatting things. Really appreciated....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding serves me, following is the code I think can work:

```py
indexs = [i for i, v in enumerate(myList) if v.isnumeric()]
listoflists = [myList[prev:cur] for prev,cur in zip(indexs,indexs[1:]+[len(myList)])]
```

Result:

```py
>>> print(listoflists)
[['1000', 'ParameterName=Device type', 'ObjectType=0x7', 'DataType=0x7', 'AccessType=ro', 'PDOMapping=0', 'ObjFlags=1', 'ParameterValue=0x00020192'], ['1001', 'ParameterName=Error register', 'ObjectType=0x7', 'DataType=0x5', 'AccessType=ro', 'PDOMapping=0', 'ObjFlags=1', 'ParameterValue=0x00'], ['1003', 'SubNumber=6', 'ParameterName=Error history', 'ObjectType=0x8']]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Just I had to change the .isnumeric with my custom conditions. I need to read a little bit more of this method.

Comment: error in the code! your missing the last element for 1003 - 'ObjectType=0x8' is missing

Comment: for indice1, indice2 in list(zip(index,index[1:]+[-1])):
    if (indice2==-1):
        indice2=len(myList)
    print(indice1,indice2)
    print(myList[indice1:indice2])

Comment: Thanks Golden, you are rgiht. change `-1` to `len(myList)` address it.
Code in answer changed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good candidate for an iterator function:

```py
from typing import Iterator, List

def get_chunks(value: List[str]) -> Iterator[List[str]]:
    chunk: List[str] = []
    for item in value:
        if is_int(item):
            # If the value is an integer, we should start a new chunk!
            yield chunk
            chunk = []
        chunk.append(item)
    yield chunk  # Make sure to yield the remaining chunk at the end


def is_int(value: str) -> bool:
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

assert list(get_chunks(["100", "foo", "200", "bar"])) == [[], ["100", "foo"], ["200", "bar"]]
```

To remove outer empty list when the sequence starts with an integer:

```py
list(filter(None, get_chunks(["100", "foo", "200", "bar"])))
# [["100", "foo"], ["200", "bar"]]
```

One could easily abstract this over the breakpoint condition function (`is_int` in this example), making it nicely composable with the various helpers in `itertools`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the prettiest way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
res_list = [i for i, value in enumerate(myList) if str.isdigit(value) == True]
result = [l.tolist() for l in np.split(myList, res_list)[1:]]
```

This uses list comprehension and `split` function, thus does not need any `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from itertools import takewhile

iterator = iter(myList[1:])
pivots = ["1000", "1001", "1003"]
list_of_lists = [[piv] + list(it.takewhile(lambda entry: entry not in pivots, iterator)) 
                 for piv in pivots]
```

[`itertools.takewhile(predicate, iterator)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), well, takes from the iterator while the predicate is true. In this case predicate is whether the current entry is a pivot or not. In every turn of the list-comprehension, the `iterator` is getting exhausted i.e. every turn we get a list of the desired `list_of_lists`. The `[1:]` slicing when making the iterator from `myList` is so that `takewhile` can start taking first pivot's entries at the very beginning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My concerning point here is that to get the list of pivots I should iterate the whole list what makes me think that I can easily append the results of that sweep to the list of lists. Maybe I am mistaken...

Answer (score 0):

```
 queryable=iter(myList)

 listOfList=[]
 sublist=[]
 for a in queryable:
     if (a.isnumeric()==True) & (len(sublist)>0):
          listOfList.append(sublist)
          sublist=[]
          sublist.append(a) 
     else:
          sublist.append(a) 
    
if(len(sublist)>0):
    listOfList.append(sublist)

print(listOfList)
```

Answer (score -3):

you may be interested in this solution.

```
myList = ['1000', 'ParameterName=Device type', 'ObjectType=0x7', 'DataType=0x7', 'AccessType=ro', 'PDOMapping=0',
          'ObjFlags=1', 'ParameterValue=0x00020192', '1001', 'ParameterName=Error register', 'ObjectType=0x7',
          'DataType=0x5', 'AccessType=ro', 'PDOMapping=0', 'ObjFlags=1', 'ParameterValue=0x00', '1003', 'SubNumber=6',
          'ParameterName=Error history', 'ObjectType=0x8']

secondlist = []
secondlist.append(myList)
print(secondlist)
```

Comment: The desired output is a list of list**s**, not a list containing one element, which is the original list.